# To keep track of changes in python requirements file and automatically sync that changes to my conda env

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, pypi

I use conda to create python virtual-environments and i pip install the python requirements.txt file in the conda env.

I want that if i make changes in my requiremesnts.txt file (add pypi package, del package, change package version), those changes should automatically get reflected in my conda environment.

How can i automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

write a shell script to monitor the file using [watch](https://serverfault.com/a/1682/503752) command, this will periodically detect for new changes and perform `pip install` if difference observed